# Is it possible to get value of views inside the listview by the click of button ouside the listview?

Tags: android, listview, button, view, onclicklistener

I have a listview where I am doing setAdapter. In the list Item I have 2 textviews and one seekbar. 
In my activity apart from the listview I have a button also. I want on the click of this button I should get the values which is set in these textview. I am setting the value in the textview by changing the seekbar.

I want to know is this possible to get the value (which is set after changing the seekbar) of the views inside listview on the click of button which is not part of the listview but is in the same activity?

Comment: Which item in your listView you want to get its values?

Comment: Textview, which is in the listview and it is changing by changing the seekbar

Comment: I know, but your listView has `many` items and each item has a TextView, so which item you want its TextView?

Comment: I have first done listview.getcount() then want to do findviewby id for that text and then in the forloop want to do textview.gettext.tostring. but I am not able to get the view anywhere other than item click for the listview. But i want to get it in the button click in the activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `HashMap` in your `Activity` and save text values in that map

Getting `TextView` object from 1st row in `ListView`:

```
View v = listView.getChildAt(0);
// if your row base layout is LinearLayout
// get it and find in this layout your TextView by id

if(v instanceof LinearLayout){
    v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
}
```

Comment: I want to do findviewbyId for the textview from the listview inside my activity. Once the setadapter for the list is already done. is that possible ? I am not getting the view on button click

Comment: this looks good I will try this tomorrow from my workstation and let you know, anyways thanks a lot.

Comment: Great, it works !!. But only thing is initially my listView.getChildAt(index); was returning null, though I was calling it after doing setadapter on the list and I was also getting values from list.getcount. But when I moved the code in the button clicklistener it works. Now my concern is it works only for visible item in the list. Is there a way I could get values for all the items in the list irrespective to that if it is visible